# Throwing exception in if condition causes if condition to be ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, selenium-webdriver

In an unit testing project with this simple code below,

```
bool isRightType = true;
if(isRightType == false)
{
    const string msg = "Für diesen Control-Typ wird die falsche Basisklasse verwendet!";
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
```

the if condition is not recognized and the exception is thrown without regarding the if condition.

This occurs only in an unit testing project with Nunit configured.
When trying the same code in a console application it works well. 
Has any body faced the same problem and has found a solution for that?

**Additional information:** 
The tests run with Selenium UI Test based on NUnit. 
What I missed in my code is that before the if condition containing the exception, an other if condition is called. (Any if condition will cause the error)
If I move the if condition below the one with the exception it will work fine.

Here is the complete method:

```
public IEnumerable<IWebElement> FindSelf()
    {
         //Keep existing instance
        if (this.self != null)
        {
            return this.self;
        }

        bool isRightType = this is YesNoRadioButtonList || this is RadioButtonList;

        if(!isRightType)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        try
        {
            self = this.selenium.FindElementsByName(selector);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {

            try
            {
                self = this.selenium.FindElementsByCss(selector);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;

            }

        }
        return self;
    }
```

Comment: Add the bool to the exception message. You'll see what happens.

Comment: Can we see your full unit test ? Is the unit test throwing an exception or is it failing ?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. I strongly suspect you're not actually testing what you think you're testing. (e.g. maybe you're actually running against old code.)

Comment: I just did a clean build, to ensure that there are no old code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isRightType = true;
if(isRightType == false)
{
    const string msg = "Für diesen Control-Typ wird die falsche Basisklasse verwendet!";
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
```

You're hardcoding isRightType to true, then immediately testing for false. There's no execution path for the if statement to be true and execute.

Comment: That was clear to me! What I wanted to show, is that even if I hardcode that, the condition is not regognized by the compiler and the exception is thrown.